# Calculate the following limits, if they exist

Tags: limits

Calculate the following limits, if they exist:

a) $$\lim_{x\to-\infty} x+\sqrt{x^2+8x+13}$$

b) $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{5^x-3^x}{x}    $$  (without using l'hospital's rule)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: MSE is not a homework answering service.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+to+-infinity+(x+%2B+sqrt(x%5E2+%2B8x%2B13)) and http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+to+0+(5%5Ex+-+3%5Ex)%2Fx

Comment: @pyrazolam I guess that's a "let me WolframAlpha that for you" kind of answer, hey? Does it help? Who knows?  Gives an answer, though you should know that any user that wants to learn ***how*** to arrive at "the answer" is required to pay WA.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (1) it is not a question, but an order, and (2) it's missing context etc.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}&(a)\;\;x+\sqrt{x^2+8x+13}=\frac{-8x-13}{x-\sqrt{x^2+8x+13}}=\frac{8+\frac{13}x}{-1-\sqrt{1+\frac8x+\frac{13}{x^2}}}\\{}\\
&(b)\;\;\lim_{x\to0}\frac{5^x-3^x}x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{5^x\log 5-3^x\log3}1=\ldots\end{align*}$$

Comment: I changed my hint to (b) as I realized the limit was $\;x\to0\;$ *and not* $\;x\to\infty\;$

Comment: I've been glad to see you back (and glad to be back myself) @DonAntonio

Comment: @amWhy Thank you, and welcome back....to both of us. :)

Comment: Part (b) should not use L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: @pyrazolam  Then answer the question yourself, without relying on software to do it for you.

Comment: @pyrazolam And anyway, OPs that are beggars (for answers & solutions) can't be choosers (who demand an answer on his/her terms)